# operating on too many entity groups in a transaction - how can I get the logs to tell me what the 5 groups are?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I understand that transactions can only operate on a maximum of 5 entity groups.
I have enabled XG transactions.

I have some fairly complex code that occasionally results in the following error:
"operating on too many entity groups in a transaction"

I'm trying to debug this, but it would be a whole lot easier if Datastore could tell me exactly  which 5 entity groups were being used, and indeed which was the 6th that took us over the limit.

I have tried turning up the log levels, but even when it fails it still doesn't tell me exactly which entity groups were involved in the failure, or even the entities.

Does anyone know how to get this information?

I am running JDO2.3, datastore API version 1.0 on Java. (sadly my app pre-dates the existence of Ojbecify etc)

Comment: Do you have a stack trace you can publish?

Comment: What language are you using? I don't know the answer but have had a similar problem in the past (Java and Objectify). In the end I solved it just by debugging and reviewing the code. Remember the 5 entity groups ["includes querying for entities by ancestor, retrieving entities by key, updating entities, and deleting entities."](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions)

Comment: thanks for the comments, I've updated my question about my environment.